# PHP Codeigniter is showing the cache when i press the back button after I logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching

After I logout from my app, when I press the back button, all of the login options for the user is still showed on the page.

After I login, when I press the back button it will show the logout version of the page.

I tried setting this in my logout controller

```
function logout() {
    $this->output->set_header('cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $this->output->set_header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    $this->tank_auth->logout();
    redirect(subdomain() . 'home');
}
```

But the cache is still there when i press the back button. How can i fix this?

-----UPDATE------

I think caching is not the problem here, I disabled caching in chrome in developer settings but my browser is still going to the secured page after logout when i press the back button.

So caching is not the problem..

Comment: I couldn't find a source so I might be wrong but if I recall correctly there was a problem/bug whereby cache control headers weren't sent properly through the output class and using the standard `header()` function resolves the issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the cache - in most browsers the back button doesn't refresh the page, it just displays the page from your history.

Comment: hello, i tried to logout in facebook and pressed the back button and it shows the main signup facebook page. how did facebook managed to do this if it just displays the page from your history?

Comment: ben: i tried to use the header function but still no luck..

Comment: You found any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello sorry for saying that caching is not the problem. Caching is the problem! I fixed this by putting this code in the index.php file of the codeigniter.

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: Best approach is to have a base controller (MY_Controller extends CI_Controller) and add the $this->output->set_header on the constructor of MY_Controller. Then anycontroller extends MY_Controller

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your controller

```
 public function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();

           $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
           $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
           $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
           $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

REad this i think its very useful to you

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html

and try this

```
$this->cache->clean();
```

or

```
$this->db->cache_delete_all();
```

Comment: I think caching is not the problem here,
I disabled caching in chrome in developer settings but my browser is still going to the secured page after logout when i press the back button.

So caching is not the problem.