# Avoid going to homepage when clicked Back button after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter latest version. I'm doing a facebook connect using php.
i followed the phpacademy's video tutorials and did a facebook login.
Everything works fine, But after i click logout, i call a function logout which does this:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');
session_destroy();
redirect('main/fb_login','refresh');
```

And activates login function and returns login view. But my problem is, upon clicking "back" button on my browser, i get my homepage with "logout" button and its not refreshed at all. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: that might be from browser cache, huh?

Comment: @Mahdi i don't seem to understand, But when every other site works just fine. There should be something wrong in my code.

Comment: oh, my bad, i got it wrong ...

Comment: Can we see your cache headers on that page please? Along the same lines [This popped up under related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745368/php-codeigniter-is-showing-the-cache-when-i-press-the-back-button-after-i-logout). Does that help?

Comment: @Mirage I have upadated my answer check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you're using templates for your views and this will be painless but make sure this is in the head of each page you don't want accessible by the back button.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE, must-revalidate">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT=0>
```

Just to explain what is happening. The page is loading from your browser cache meaning the browser thinks your user is still logged in. The above lines make the browser revalidate the page on every load and won't load it from it's own cache.

Comment: i added this, still its the same. Any other advice?

Comment: i added this `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");` along with your code on the top my web page. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line of code at the start of your home page function:

> ```
>  if(!$this->session->userdata('username')) header('location: main/fb_login');
> ```

Edit:  Try the following code.

```
    public function home() 
    { 
        if(!$this->session->userdata('username')) header('location: main/fb_login');
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
```

Comment: This is my home function, `public function home()
 {
 if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
  
  $this->load->view('home');

 }
 else
 {
  redirect('main/fb_login','refresh');
 }
 }`
Where do i add this?

Comment: The page is loading from the browser cache, no amount of code is going to fix it inside the PHP because the page is not technically loading again, just displaying what was already there.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check whether the user is logged on or not by using if condition as:

```
  function homepage(){     
     if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        //code for homepage
        $this->load->view('homepage');//there should be file in you view folder homepage.php
     }else{
        redirect('main/fb_login','refresh');
     }
  }
```

this will prevent from going to home page.

and make sure that you have loaded session library:

```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','form_validation');
```

and if every thing is fine in the above statements then try by writing

```
 session_start();
```

in the constructor after this statement

```
 parent::__construct();
```

hope it will help!

Comment: Yes, i added this. But still when i do `http://localhost:81/tag/main/logout` 
and then click on back button, i get my logged in page. Same problem.

Comment: It's enabled in my autoload.php

Comment: Won't work since the page is being called from the browser cache and not being loaded.