# How to deny user access when back in browser is clicked and user have already logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I want to deny user access when user is not logged in. So, what I did is put this code in every function of my controller:

```
if((!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))){
            redirect(site_url()."/Login/logged_in",'refresh');
}
```

And I also have this one:

```
 public function logged_in(){
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if(!isset($logged_in) || $logged_in !== true){
       $this->load->view('ErrorAccess');
    }
}
```

Then when I tried to logout and click the back button in the browser, I actually can access the previous page that I have been into. How am I going to deny access for that situation?

Comment: can you click things on the back button and still have them work? the page doesn't necessarily reload when you hit the back button so it could be denying access.  try reloading the page after hitting the back button and see what happens

Comment: @yhussain, I can just view things in the previous page when I click the back button in the browser. The time I click buttons in that page, is the time I will be redirected to the **access denied** page. I actually don't know how to reload after hitting the back button..

Comment: @yhussain, where will I put this? `header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");`

Comment: Atlast, found an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745368/php-codeigniter-is-showing-the-cache-when-i-press-the-back-button-after-i-logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting this in the index.php of the codeigniter file:

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

credit to: Kevin Lee

[PHP Codeigniter is showing the cache when i press the back button after I logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745368/php-codeigniter-is-showing-the-cache-when-i-press-the-back-button-after-i-logout)